# Issue with Binance API access from Heroku platform (ccxt library)

Tags: heroku

I had a problem using the ccxt library to work with the Binance exchange on the Heroku platform. Calling the exchange.fetch_ticker('BTC/USDT') method throws an ExchangeNotAvailable exception with the message "Service unavailable from a restricted location according to 'b. Eligibility' in https://www.binance.com/en/terms. Please contact customer service if you believe you received this message in error." I understand that this is due to restrictions on access to Binance from certain locations.

I'm asking for help in resolving this issue, as I need to get data from the Binance exchange in order to calculate the amount of Bitcoin.

I would be grateful for any help or recommendations.

Thank you!

Region:
United States
Stack:
heroku-22

I also tried to add a proxy server, it didn't work for me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Binance Global has restricted access to USA, hence why you get that error. To resolve that, you need to access the US endpoint.
If the currency you wish to access is just BTC USDT, direct your request to the US endpoint `https://api.binance.us/api/v3/`

Note: US market data are limited, so if you want to access more pairs that isn't in the US endpoint, you will need to change your heroku app server to Europe then you can use the Binance Global endpoint.

Answer (score -1):

I pass the price in dlls to this function, and it returns it to me in bitcoin:

```py
import cxt

def calculate_bitcoin_amount(total_cost):
    # Create a ccxt client for fetching market data
    exchange = ccxt.binance()

    # Get the current exchange rate for BTC/USD
    ticker = exchange.fetch_ticker('BTC/USDT')
    exchange_rate = ticker['close']

    # Calculate the Bitcoin amount based on the exchange rate
    bitcoin_amount = total_cost / exchange_rate

    # Round the Bitcoin amount to 8 decimal places
    bitcoin_amount = round(bitcoin_amount, 8)

    return bitcoin_amount
```

The code works fine for me (I'm from Ukraine), but it doesn't work on Heroku servers in the USA.